# Getting :: Could not initialize class reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfiguration

Tags: project-reactor

I'm getting the following exception while placing webclient POST
Response:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfiguration

```
        DBServiceRequest dbServiceRq = new DBServiceRequest();
        Map<String, Object> criteria = new HashMap<>();
        criteria.put("CKTNAME", "8249");
        criteria.put("REGION", "NE");
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        dbServiceRq.setRequestQuery(cdmCktdetailsGivenCktWithRegion);
        dbServiceRq.setCriteria(criteria);
        BodyInserter<Object, ReactiveHttpOutputMessage> inserter = BodyInserters.fromValue(dbServiceRq);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = webClient.post().uri(getDataServiceUri()).body(inserter)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).exchange().block().toEntity(String.class).block();
```

Comment: could you provide more information about your pom.xml/build.gradle file? It might be a dependency problem.